# csv.reader fooled by line terminators inside data fields

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file downloaded from the internet that I need to parse. Python with the `csv.reader` seems to be the tool of choice, however my input has line terminators (both `\r` and `\n`) inside some data fields. This makes for incomplete lines.  The field data are surrounded by apostrophes so the issue ought to be avoidable - but how?

I tried with and without the `dialect='excel'`, no difference. I know I need to apply `iconv` to my input data, too.

```
import csv
with open(INFILNAM,'rb') as csvfile:
 infil = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
 for row in infil:
  print ', '.join(row)
```

Sample of the output, "aaa " preceeding each line for clarity:

```
aaa  , LF0121, La Trancli�re, Base ULM Acc�s priv�, 9/03/2011, 20/02/2012, 20/02/2012, 46.095556, 5.286667, N 46 05 44, E 005 17 12, 820 ft, Tour de piste imp�ratif du c�t� autoroute. Ne pas voler au dessus du village de la Trancli�re. Presque toujours d�gag�., 1, herbe, '36, 40, 640, '18-36, , , , , , 123.5, , , , roger.emeriat@wanadoo.fr, +33 4 74 46 84 34, Village le plus proche : essence , hotels, etc = Pont D'ain � 4, 5 km. En cas de brume : altiport de corlier a environ 15 km
aaa  
aaa  Infos suppl�mentaires : Laurent Pradel St� Vectral. repr�sentant appareil savannah dans la r�gion. Possibilit� essai de l'appareil en vol. T�l : 04 74 35 60 00 email vectral@wanadoo.fr, 
aaa  , LF0125, Lavours, Base ULM Autorisation OBLIGATOIRE , 8/03/2011, 24/06/2015, 25/06/2015, 45.795, 5.77361099999996, N 45 47 42, E 005 46 25, 768 ft, TDP � l'est
aaa  Eviter les villages en rouge sur la photo, faire la vent-arri�re sur le Rh�ne.
aaa  attention aux rouleaux par vent de travers, 1, herbe, '01, 20, 450, '01-19, herbe, , , , 'Inconnue, 123.5, , , , , +33 4 79 42 11 57, attention, base Hydro ULM club de Lavours � proximit� , 
aaa  , LF0151, Corbonod Seyssel, A�rodrome Priv� Avec Restrictions Autorisation OBLIGATOIRE , 6/09/2011, 10/01/2015, 11/01/2015, 45.960629840733, 5.817818641662598, N 45 57 38, E 005 49 04, 1175 ft, Arriv�e dans axe de la piste puis, du centre vent arri�re main gauche 
aaa  Suivre le plan imperatif (photo jointe), 1, dur, '01, 15, 400, '01-19, herbe, , , , 'Inconnue, 123.5, , 6, Restauration � proximit�, dudunoyer@yahoo.fr, +33 6 07 38 20 15, PPR obligatoire pour tous,ULM et avion (arr�t� pr�fectoral). Contacter le Pdt de l'AAC gestionnaire.
```

Comment: You should show a sample of the csv file you are having issue with.

Comment: @Anand: I'd love to but find no way to do it meaningfully. Cut & paste creates a mess.

Comment: copy & paste and then use the `{}` button on top after highlighting the copy pasted item.

Comment: You could provide a link to the csv file if it is available.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Improvements to multi-line handling were added in 2.5, see [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Comment: @Martin: Python is 2.7.6, on Ubuntu if that is relevant. Always updated as suggested.

Comment: @Martin: the data is downloaded from the below url, one needs to be registered there. Best have some French, too. http://basulm.ffplum.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10&Itemid=84

Comment: What do you get if you just use `csv.reader()` with the defaults? i.e. no delimiter, quotechar or dialect.

Comment: what file did you download?

Comment: I have put the first lines of the file online at (http://users.skynet.be/fa348739/temp/mystery.csv) it can be downloaded with wget or such. It holds data for 8 spreadsheet rows: the header and 7 data rows.

Comment: using "raw" mode as requested doesn't help at all. "Obsol�te;Code terrain;Toponyme;Type;Date creation;Derni�re modification;Date validation;Position;Latitude;Longitude;Altitude;Consignes;Nombre de pistes;Nature premi�re piste;Axe pr�f�rentiel premi�re piste;Largeur premi�re piste;Longueur premi�re piste;Orientation premi�re piste;Nature deuxi�me piste;Axe pr�f�rentiel deuxi�me piste;Largeur deuxi�me piste;Longueur deuxi�me piste;Orientation deuxi�me piste;Radio;Carburant;Facilit�s;Facilit�s en clair;Email de contact;T�l�phone;Informations compl�mentaires
;"LF0121";"La Trancli�re";"Base ULM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is being parsed fine; the new lines are just being printed again in your print statement.

Replacing `print ', '.join(row)` with `print row` gives the following output:

```
['Obsol\xe8te', 'Code terrain', 'Toponyme', 'Type', 'Date creation', 'Derni\xe8re modification', 'Date validation', 'Position', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Altitude', 'Consignes', 'Nombre de pistes', 'Nature premi\xe8re piste', 'Axe pr\xe9f\xe9rentiel premi\xe8re piste', 'Largeur premi\xe8re piste', 'Longueur premi\xe8re piste', 'Orientation premi\xe8re piste', 'Nature deuxi\xe8me piste', 'Axe pr\xe9f\xe9rentiel deuxi\xe8me piste', 'Largeur deuxi\xe8me piste', 'Longueur deuxi\xe8me piste', 'Orientation deuxi\xe8me piste', 'Radio', 'Carburant', 'Facilit\xe9s', 'Facilit\xe9s en clair', 'Email de contact', 'T\xe9l\xe9phone', 'Informations compl\xe9mentaires']
['', 'LF0121', 'La Trancli\xe8re', 'Base ULM Acc\xe8s priv\xe9', '8/03/2011', '6/09/2015', '12/09/2015', '46.095556, 5.286667', 'N 46 05 44', 'E 005 17 12', '820 ft', 'Tour de piste imp\xe9ratif du c\xf4t\xe9 autoroute. Ne pas voler au dessus du village de la Trancli\xe8re. Presque toujours d\xe9gag\xe9.', '1', 'herbe', "'36", '40', '640', "'18-36", 'herbe', '', '', '', "'Inconnue", '123.5', '', '', '', 'roger.emeriat@wanadoo.fr', '+33 4 74 46 84 34', "Village le plus proche : essence , hotels, etc = Pont D'ain \xe0 4, 5 km. En cas de brume : altiport de Corlier a environ 15 km\r\r\r\n\r\nInfos suppl\xe9mentaires : Laurent Pradel St\xe9 Vectral. repr\xe9sentant appareil savannah dans la r\xe9gion. Possibilit\xe9 essai de l'appareil en vol. T\xe9l : 04 74 35 60 00 email vectral@wanadoo.fr", '']
['', 'LF0125', 'Lavours', 'Base ULM Autorisation OBLIGATOIRE ', '8/03/2011', '24/06/2015', '25/06/2015', '45.795, 5.77361099999996', 'N 45 47 42', 'E 005 46 25', '768 ft', "TDP \xe0 l'est\r\r\nEviter les villages en rouge sur la photo, faire la vent-arri\xe8re sur le Rh\xf4ne.\r\r\nattention aux rouleaux par vent de travers", '1', 'herbe', "'01", '20', '450', "'01-19", 'herbe', '', '', '', "'Inconnue", '123.5', '', '', '', '', '+33 4 79 42 11 57', 'attention, base Hydro ULM club de Lavours \xe0 proximit\xe9 ', '']
['', 'LF0151', 'Corbonod Seyssel', 'A\xe9rodrome Priv\xe9 Avec Restrictions Autorisation OBLIGATOIRE ', '6/09/2011', '10/01/2015', '11/01/2015', '45.960629840733, 5.817818641662598', 'N 45 57 38', 'E 005 49 04', '1175 ft', 'Arriv\xe9e dans axe de la piste puis, du centre vent arri\xe8re main gauche \r\r\nSuivre le plan imperatif (photo jointe)', '1', 'dur', "'01", '15', '400', "'01-19", 'herbe', '', '', '', "'Inconnue", '123.5', '', '6', 'Restauration \xe0 proximit\xe9', 'dudunoyer@yahoo.fr', '+33 6 07 38 20 15', "PPR obligatoire pour tous,ULM et avion (arr\xeat\xe9 pr\xe9fectoral). Contacter le Pdt de l'AAC gestionnaire.\r\r\nRadio obligatoire pour tous + qualif montagne souhait\xe9e pour avion. Interdit ULM classe 1\r\r\nSurvol interdit \xe0 l'Est du Rh\xf4ne entre Seyssel et Culoz: Zone Biotope Natura 2000\r\r\n\xc9colage et  TDP interdit\r\r\nRadio 123.5 car piste l\xe9g\xe8rement convexe.\r\r\r\n\r\nCamping 1.5 KM\r\r\nResto + h\xf4tel : 2Km", '']
```

As you can see, the new lines within quotes have not created new rows.

Comment: That was it indeed; as so often happens, I was looking for the trouble at the wrong place. The **print ', '.join(row)** comes from the product documentation, as being the most basic usage; talk of **confusing the masses** ...